# Cannot transform an entity to an immutable Value Object field used in form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I'm having troubles with a rather complex form. A child of this form is a Value Object quite similar to what can be found in the doctrine documentation (ie. an Address Value Object, with text fields and a Country Entity field). I have no trouble to display the form with each field of the Address Value Object but when I submit it, a Property Access Exception is thrown saying there's neither property country, nor any setter method on the Value Object. Since the Value Object is immutable, this exception is expected.

```
   $addressFormBuilder = $app['form.factory']->createNamedBuilder('address', 'form', new Address('street','postalCode','city','region',$country_1), [
        'data_class' => 'Address'
    ]);
   $addressFormBuilder
        ->add('street', 'text', ['constraints' => [new Assert\NotBlank ,new Assert\Length(['max' => 50])]])
        ->add('postal_code', 'text', ['constraints' => [new Assert\NotBlank ,new Assert\Length(['max' => 50])]])
        ->add('city', 'text', ['constraints' => [new Assert\NotBlank ,new Assert\Length(['max' => 50])]])
        ->add('region', 'text', ['constraints' => [new Assert\NotBlank ,new Assert\Length(['max' => 50])]])
        ->add('country', 'entity', [
            'class' => 'Countries',
            'choice_label' => 'label',
            'em' => $this->em,
            'placeholder' => ''
        ]);

   $addressFormBuilder->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(function($originalDescription) {
        return $originalDescription;
    }, function($submittedDescription) {
        // Exception thrown before this part
        var_dump($submittedDescription);exit;
        return new Addresses(null, null, null, null, null);
    }));
```

The trouble is actually that I cannot transform the submitted Address to a new one (only way to handle immutable Value Objects). Since the transformers handle the submitted entity before transforming it, the transformer I added to the address field is probably called to late, after the attempt to set the modified Country Entity to the original Address.

So I wonder if there's a way to handle this use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony's forms were not designed to handle immutable objects as entities, so you stumble onto this problems when you try to do that.

Anyhow, the creator of the forms himself has posted a solution to this problem: https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/

It boils down to this: **use data transformers**

```
public function mapDataToForms($data, $forms)
{
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    $forms['amount']->setData($data ? $data->getAmount() : 0);
    $forms['currency']->setData($data ? $data->getCurrency() : 'EUR');
}
```

and

```
public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
{
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    $data = new Money(
        $forms['amount']->getData(), 
        $forms['currency']->getData()
    );
}
```

Comment: Another approach is to plug in your own property access object and give it direct access to the value object's private/protected variables.  Same thing that Doctrine 2 does.  Or just bite the bullet and add getter/setter methods.